# Why jQuery event loop is interrupted on exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

After a weird behaviour of our application (using strophe XMPP and jQuery), we have discovered that the jQuery event loop is synchronous and does not catch exception.

It means that if the first event handler raises an exception, the second one is never called.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind('foo', onFoo);
    $(document).bind('bar', onBar); 

    $(document).trigger('foo');
    $(document).trigger('bar');
});

function onFoo(e) { 
    console.log('listener onFoo');
    throw 'fail onFoo';
}

function onBar(e) {
    console.log('listener onBar'); // not called
}
```

We expected to see two outputs, but the second one : "listener onBar" was never displayed.

See JQuery code, in "trigger" function, there is no try/catch pattern during the loop of the handlers.

```js
while ( (cur = eventPath[i++]) && !event.isPropagationStopped() ) {
    event.type = i > 1 ?
        bubbleType :
        special.bindType || type;

    // jQuery handler
    handle = ( jQuery._data( cur, "events" ) || {} )[ event.type ] && jQuery._data( cur, "handle" );
    if ( handle ) {
        handle.apply( cur, data );
    }
... (line 4998 in JQuery 1.10.2)
```

We have been surprised by this implementation.

In pure JavaScript, all the handlers are called even if one of them crashed: http://jsfiddle.net/bamthomas/kgS7A/2/.

**Does someone know why jQuery team does not allow the execution of the next handler even if the previous one crashed ? Why exceptions are not caught?**

**Why didn't they use JavaScript event handler?**

Comment: "Why doesn't jQuery catch exceptions?" - most likely it's because noone thought this might be a problem. You are welcome to send a pull request to their github repo.

Comment: If your event handler can throw, then it's your responsibility to catch the exception. Why would you expect (or even want) that `trigger` does that?

Comment: As much as the discovery that jQuery doesn't catch exceptions might be useful, I don't think this question can be answered objectively...

Comment: @Tomalak It's kinda nice if an unhandled exception in one module or even a userscript doesn't take down the entire application.

Comment: Avoid bind, it's deprecated (use `.on`).

Comment: Also never ever ever throw strings. [A string is not an error.](http://www.devthought.com/2011/12/22/a-string-is-not-an-error/)

Comment: @Jan Yes, but the body of `trigger` is the wrong place to do that, IMHO. Apart from that: Is having your application continue to run in an undefined state better than having it crash entirely?

Comment: @Tomalak given that exceptions don't take down the event loop (though that would be fancy)... yes, I'd like to have my event handlers run.

Comment: @Tomalak The answer to that question is just what you consider to be a deathly exception.  In my experience, I define there to be many errors in the application and few exceptions.  Exceptions kill applications usually, but errors are recoverable because they're generally there to help the user, the system, and the developer.

Comment: @kevin628 unhandled exceptions are usually bugs or unhandleable situations.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, that's what I am saying.  But I have always developed applications to have as few unhandle-able situations as possible.  Null pointer exceptions for example, that can either be solved by testing calling code to ensure it never passes null or I can gracefully handle a null value.  No need to take down the whole application in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of [this loop taken from the `.dispatch` source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L380-L400):

```
while ((handleObj = matched.handlers[j++]) && !event.isImmediatePropagationStopped()) {

    // Triggered event must either 1) have no namespace, or
    // 2) have namespace(s) a subset or equal to those in the bound event (both can have no namespace).
    if (!event.namespace_re || event.namespace_re.test(handleObj.namespace)) {

        event.handleObj = handleObj;
        event.data = handleObj.data;

        ret = ((jQuery.event.special[handleObj.origType] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler)
        .apply(matched.elem, args);

        if (ret !== undefined) {
            if ((event.result = ret) === false) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
}
```

As you can see, there is no try/catch around `.apply`.

That's the way it has been for [years](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3999d39b8437f13193ef1098e36227ffaca18362/src/event.js#L372) and [years and years](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/8e53f7b5d6716e60d8c8ea7e167f2b187aae9d89/src/event.js#L209).

Even if they wanted, changing it now will break too much existing code. Remember, lots of things in jQuery that seem arbitrary now were born in another time.

You can of course 'fix' this in your own code (wrapping it in a try/catch with error message), but you'll surprise pretty much everyone else.

Comment: "changing it now will break too much existing code." - can you provide an example?

Comment: @JanDvorak yes. There is lots of code in the wild there that was coded using the famous 'throw jQuery at it until it works'. For what we know, someone might have code similar to OP's and they're using throwing as a way to prevent the other listeners from running.

Comment: Ew. That is a terrible way to achieve that goal. Yet - good point, thanks.